# A: What are you doing. B: "I am studying a lesson/lesson/lessons/my lessons." Aren't all these answers unidiomatic?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, idiomatic-language

Imagine, you see a non-native speaker sitting at a table with pencil and a book and notebook etc. You think he is either doing his homework or he is preparing for an exam at school.

You ask him: **"What are you doing."**

He says **"I am studying my lessons."**

This sentence sounded unnatural to me, because you would not **"study your lessons"** but you **"learn your lesson"** in English. And **"learning your lesson"** is more about life, rather than subjects at school.

And I thought about what might have been a better version. Maybe **"I am studying a lesson/lessons."** However this would not sound idiomatic either.

And finally I think **"I am studying."** would be enough in itself, because it intrinsically refers to school subjects.

But I still wonder, whether **"I am studying a lesson/lessons"** is ever used by native speakers in the sense they are doing what they were assigned at school or they are preparing for an exam at school?

Comment: I wouldn't normally say someone was "studying a lesson". ***Lessons*** normally refers to tuition sessions delivered *by the teacher to the pupil(s) **in a classroom***. If you see someone "studying" at a table with writing instruments, textbooks, etc.,  he's probably doing ***homework***. Or perhaps he's "going over, reviewing" a lesson he previously had in school.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an AmE speaker, "I am studying a lesson" sounds unidiomatic. Some alternatives are:

- I am studying
- I am revising
- I am studying for my exam
- I am reviewing my work from class

If you wanted to say you were doing homework, you literally just say "I'm doing homework".